# Как мне сказать чтобы в печать вывел значение всех индексов которые были заполнены?

Tags: php, php7, php5, php7.2

Ошибку даёт на 9-ой строчке, выводит просто Array, как мне ему сказать чтобы вывел все значение заполненных индексов?

```
$arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $arr[$i] = rand(1, 100);
    //echo $mass.'<br>';
}
echo $arr;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

Или:

```
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Получилось типа:
Array (
.....
.....
)
А можно вывести таким образом чтобы термина Array и скобок не было?

Comment: Функцией print_r нельзя. Для этого лучше цикл использовать

Answer (score 0):

print_r - печатает читабельную информацию о переменной.

```
print_r($arr);
```